# Docker `Disk image location` setting doesn't work on macOS

Tags: macos, docker

I’m traing to change `Disk image location` from default `/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0` to my External SSD volume SSDData (ExtFAT) `/Volumes/SSDData/Hyper-V/Docker/DockerDesktop` but after restart docker desktop it returns to default value? Why and how to fix? Please help

```
macOS Catalina 10.15.7 
Docker Desktop 2.5.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by completely reinstallation.